# How to get sum value for fields based on input field in elasticsearch (input field and sum output fields are different)

Tags: go, elasticsearch

This is document present in elastic search and wants to output based fields in which it returns the sum of the high and medium and which be greater than zero, the value of high and medium must be greater than > 0

```
         {
            "host_id": 1,
            "hostname": "Hostname1",
            "businesshierarchy": {
                "businessunit": "NON Unit",
                "Location":"Un",
                "Application":"App1"
            },
            "updatedts": 1601894092,
            "critical": 0,
            "high": 1,
            "medium": 1,
            "low": 0
        },
        {
            "host_id": 2,
            "hostname": "Hostname2",
            "businesshierarchy": {
                "businessunit": "One Unit",
                "Location":"Un",
                "Application":"App2"
            },
            "updatedts": 1601894092,
            "critical": 0,
            "high": 1,
            "medium": 2,
            "low": 0
        },
        {
            "host_id": 3,
            "hostname": "Hostname3",
            "businesshierarchy": {
                "businessunit": "NON Unit",
                "Location":"Uk",
                "Application":"App2"
            },
            "updatedts": 1601894092,
            "critical": 0,
            "high": 2,
            "medium": 2,
            "low": 0
        }
```

Is there are any query or method to get output like in elastic search?

1. based on location

   Location - Un
   High - 2
   medium - 3

   Location - Uk
   High - 2
   medium - 2
2. Based on application

   Application -  App1
   High - 1
   medium - 1

   Application -  App2
   High - 3
   medium - 4
3. or based on hostname

   hostname -  Hostname1
   High - 1
   medium - 1

   hostname -  Hostname2
   High - 1
   medium - 2

   hostname -  Hostname3
   High - 2
   medium - 2

Similarly for businessunit. The field name passed dynamically like businessunit, hostname, application, location-based on it want to get count High and medium value like the above output.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: yeah, it works fine!! my mapping is different just need to add a keyword for  "field": "businesshierarchy.Location.keyword "

Comment: glad it worked for you. Can you please accept and upvote my answer as well as it worked for you 

Comment: Thank u for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index mapping, index data(same as that given in question), search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "hostname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "businesshierarchy": {
        "properties": {
          "Location": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Application": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "businesshierarchy.Location"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_user_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "high",
                "medium"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "high_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "high"
          }
        },
        "medium_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "medium"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

**Based on the location**

```
"aggregations": {
    "user": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Un",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 1,
                    "medium": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 1,
                    "medium": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 2.0       <-- note this
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 3.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Uk",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 2,
                    "medium": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 2.0                       <-- note this
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 2.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**For querying on the basis of application replace terms aggregation like this:**

```
"aggs": {
        "user": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "businesshierarchy.Application"
          },
```

The following search result will be there:

```
 "aggregations": {
    "user": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "App2",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 2,
                    "medium": 2
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 1,
                    "medium": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 3.0
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 4.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "App1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 1,
                    "medium": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 1.0
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 1.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**For querying on the basis of hostname replace terms aggregation like this:**

```
"aggs": {
    "user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hostname"
      },
```

Search Results will be :

```
"aggregations": {
    "user": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Hostname1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 1,
                    "medium": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 1.0
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Hostname2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 1,
                    "medium": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 1.0
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 2.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Hostname3",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_user_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64218649",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "high": 2,
                    "medium": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "high_sum": {
            "value": 2.0
          },
          "medium_sum": {
            "value": 2.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use this query to get the excepted result

```
  {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "medium": {
                            "gt": 0
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "high": {
                            "gt": 0
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "fieldnames": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "hostname.keyword"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "medium": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "medium"
                  }
                },
                "high": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "high"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "size": 0
        }
```

**Search result for this look like this**

```
"aggregations": {
        "fieldnames": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "ALL Unit",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "high": {
                        "value": 0.0
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "value": 7.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "Latest Unit",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "high": {
                        "value": 0.0
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "value": 5.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "NO Unit",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "high": {
                        "value": 1.0
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "value": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

In case if we need the result for location and application, just need to change
**for Location**

```
"aggs": {
                "fieldnames": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "businesshierarchy.Application.keyword"
                  }
```

**for Application**

```
"aggs": {
                    "fieldnames": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "businesshierarchy.Location.keyword"
                      }
```

if the mapping is something like this,

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "hostname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "businesshierarchy": {
        "properties": {
          "Location": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "Application": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no need for adding .keyword to

```
"terms": {
             "field": "businesshierarchy.Location"
           }
```